# HTML WebKit: Unexplainable huge gap between iFrame and section tag

Tags: html, css, iframe

There's a huge gap between an iFrame and a section tag. In my 360x640 Galaxy S5 (Chrome) it shows, but not in the developer tools of Google Chrome (by simulating that resolution), so my conclusion is that it's something that only happens on WebKit. I've scattered through all of the html and css files, and there's no media query nor configuration that seems to cause the gap. I've tried by globally setting section to padding:0 and margin:0, but nothing changed. It is looking like this at the moment:

[image: Huge Gap]
I don't want to share the HTML and CSS files yet, because they are very large, but if you can deduce what's going on I'd really appreciate, otherwise just ask for the files. Thanks in advance

Comment: Browser used on the mobile ?

Comment: Google Chrome @Troyer

Comment: Refer to this on [mcve]